# Is the Shechina present when a person is mourning or distraught?

Tags: tefilla, simchah-joy-happiness, suffering, shechinah

It's said the Shechinah is present only where there's joy ([Tractate Shabbat 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.30b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Yet we are also taught to cry to Hashem during times of suffering, depression, sorrow, mourning, etc. Is the Shechinah present when one has no simcha in their heart?

Comment: עמו אנכי בצרה (תהילים צא)

Comment: @JoelK, thank you but that does not directly address the question.

Comment: Can anyone else offer input for this question?

Comment: From what I can tell, the gemara isn't talking about the presence of the Shechinah in general but the dwelling of the Shechinah upon a person, as evident from the example brought from the case of Elisha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If exile, i.e. the forcible uprooting of a people, qualifies as a time of sorrow and difficulty, then there are a several instances where it writes that the Shechinah accompanies the Jews when they are exiled.

Firstly, refer to the [Mechilta 12:40](https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_d%27Rabbi_Yishmael.12.40.1?vhe=Mekhilta_--_Wikisource&lang=bi):

> וכן את מוצא בכל מקום שגלו שכינה עמהם. גלו למצרים שכינה עמהם, שנאמר הנגלה נגליתי אל בית אביך בהיותם במצרים (שמואל א ב'). גלו לבבל שכינה עמהן, שנאמר ושמתי כסאי בעילם (ירמיה מט). גלו לאדום שכינה עמהן, שנאמר מי זה בא מאדום חמוץ בגדים מבצרה (ישעיה סג). וכשעתידין לחזור, כביכול שכינה עמהן. שנאמר ושב ה' אלהיך (דברים ל) אינו אומר והשיב אלא ושב. ואומר אתי מלבנון כלה (שיר השירים ד) וכי מלבנון היא באה, והלא מלבנון הוא עולה. כביכול אני ואת (ללבנון) עולים
>
> And thus do you find, that wherever they were exiled, the Shechinah was with them. They were exiled to Egypt — the Shechinah was with them, viz. ([I Samuel 2:27](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.2.27?lang=bi)) "Did I not reveal Myself to your father's house when they were in Egypt? They were exiled to Bavel — the Shechinah was with them, viz. ([Isaiah 43:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.43.14?lang=bi)) "For your sake I was exiled to Bavel." They were exiled to Eilam — the Shechinah was with them, viz. ([Jeremiah 49:38](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.49.38?lang=bi)) "and I set My throne in Eilam." They were exiled to Edom — the Shechinah was with them, viz. ([Isaiah 63:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.63.1?lang=bi)) "Who is This coming from Edom, His garments crimsoned, from Batzrah?" And when they return in the future, the Shechinah will be with them, viz. ([Devarim 30:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.30.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) "And veshav the L rd your G d." It is not written "veheshiv" ("He will return" [you]), but "veshav" ("He [Himself] will return.") and it is written (Song of Songs 4:8) "With Me from Levanon (the Temple), My bride (Israel); with Me from Levanon come." Now is she (Israel) coming from Levanon? Is she not ascending to Levanon? (The intent is: You and I were exiled from Levanon) and we will ascend) together) to Levanon. (Sefaria translation and notation)

Similarly, refer to the Maharal in his [Chiddushei Agados on Berachos 8a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Berakhot.8a.1?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi):

> ואמר אמר הקב"ה פדאני ולבני כו' כי השכינה היא בגלות כמ"ש עמו אנכי בצרה וגם שכל ל' המזמור דוד אמרו זה הפסוק ע"ש שהשכינה אמרה פדה בשלום נפשי עם מקרב לי מלשון קרובים דהיינו בני ודו"ק
>
> And the Holy Blessed One says, [this person has] redeemed Me and My children, etc. (Berachot 8a) -- for God's Presence is in exile, as it was written "I will be with him in distress" ([Psalms 91:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.91.15?lang=bi)). And also with all of the 30 "psalms of David" they said this pasuk, see there. God's Presence says, "He has redeemed my soul in peace from the battle [קרב] against me" ([Psalms 55:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.55.19?lang=bi)), this is the language of those who are close [קרובים], that is to say my children.

Perhaps the [Ohr HaChaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Deuteronomy.33.1.8?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) hakadosh on Devarim 33:1 puts it best:

> אולי שנתכוין לצרף עמהם הנעלמה מעיני כל חי שהיא השכינה שהיא עם ישראל אפילו בצרה דכתיב (תהלים צ''א טו) עמו אנכי בצרה
>
> It may be a veiled reference to the fact that even when the Israelites are in exile, some part of G-d's presence never completely deserts them. This concept is based on Psalms 91,15: "I will be with him in distress."

---

More generally speaking, refer to the [Yerushalmi Berachos 9:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Berakhot.9.1.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where it demonstrates that Hashem personally, as it were, comes to the aid of someone who is in distress.

> רִבִּי יוּדָן אָמַר מִשְּׁמֵיהּ דִּידֵיהּ בָּשָׂר וְדָם יֵשׁ לוֹ פַּטְרוֹן. **אִם בָּאָת לוֹ עֵת צָרָה** אֵינוֹ נִכְנַס אֶצְלוֹ פִּתְאוֹם. אֶלָּא בָּא וְעָמַד עַל פִּתְחוֹ שֶׁל פַּטְרוֹנוֹ וְקוֹרֵא לְעַבְדּוֹ אוֹ לְבֵן בֵּיתוֹ וְהוּא אוֹמֵר אִישׁ פְּלוֹנִי עוֹמֵד עַל פֶּתַח חֲצֵירָךְ. שֶׁמָּא מַכְנִיסוֹ וְשֶׁמָּא מַנִּיחוֹ. **אֲבָל הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אֵינוֹ כֵן אִם בָּאָה עַל אָדָם צָרָה לֹא יְצַווַח לֹא לְמִיכָאֵל וְלֹא לְגַבְרִיאֵל אֶלָּא לִי יְצַווַח וַאֲנִי עוֹנֶה לוֹ מִיַּד** הָהוּא דִּכְתִיב כָּל אֲשֶׁר יִקְרָא בְּשֵׁם ה יְמַלֵּט.
>
> Rebbi Yudan said in his own name: Flesh and blood has a protector. **If someone is in distress**, he does not enter the protector’s place suddenly but rather stands at his door and calls his slave or member of the household and that one will say: "Ploni is standing at the door of your courtyard." Perhaps he will make him enter, maybe he will let him stand. **But the Holy One, praise to Him, is not like this: If a person is in distress, he should cry neither to Michoel nor to Gavriel, rather he should cry to Me and I shall answer him immediately**; that is what is written ([Yoel 3:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Joel.3.5?lang=bi)): “Every one who calls on the name of G-d will escape.”